# change NSB schedule at runtime

Tags: nservicebus

I can see over [here](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/search?q=schedule) that there is some work planned on the NServiceBus Scheduler.

So what is currently a good approach to change the schedule at runtime?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why a schedule would change after the endpoint is running?

Comment: You can add comments to the specific issues in GitHub.

Comment: @AdamFyles I moved the interval of the schedule in a config file. So I was looking at changing this interval at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how we did it via the fluent configuration:

```
public static class ConfigureTaskStorage
{
    public static Configure UseConfigFileStorageForTaskSchedule(this Configure config)
    {
        if (null == config)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("config");

        config.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<ITaskScheduleStorage>(()=> new ConfigStorage(),DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance);
        return config;
    }
}
```